# How to avoid having too many similar columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

Lets say I have a table with information about all the products I am selling and a table with information for my seven stores, each store has its own id. Now I want to crate a table which tells me how much of a certain product I have in stock in total and how much of it do I have in each store. I am thinking of having every store be a column in the new table. What is a clever way to do that? Is there a better way to deal with it? And can I have a table with no primary key?

[image]

Comment: **YIKES** if ever you see [name]1, [name]2, ... [name]n run for the hills! This IS NOT normalized and will be a pain in the ... ever after. What happens when stores 5 & 6 merge so that you can open 3 new stores? Keep normalizing the model. Also, do prices change over time? or could the price differ between stores?

Comment: I have no idea how to do the normalization in this case. That is what I am asking. How can I reduce number of columns without having multiple entrees for a single product?

Comment: There are many references to normalization to research, and there already is a relevant answer below. You have many products and have several stores, each store has many of the products. So at some point there has to be *multiple references* to a product (but you only need one master record to define a product). I was stressing a data model symptom that clearly indicates a need for more normalization.

Comment: @Used_By_Already & waterdrinker Such multiple columnity is typically bad design, but it has nothing to do with ["normalization"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) either in the sense of higher NFs or the (confused & fuzzy) sense of "atomic"-only values. The notion that there is something wrong with "multiple entries" is also [misconceived](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44539858/3404097).

Answer (score 4):

Stock table, where you should have:

- ProductId (FK)
- StoreId (FK)
- Stock

If you want to have total stock for stores - create a view with GROUP BY.
For PK you can use the complex as ProductId + StoreId or create an artificial one.
Primary Key is almost always highly recommended.