# Where is the limit to what would be considered data duplication in a database?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

What is the line that you should draw when normalising data, in terms of data duplication? i.e would you say that 2 employees who share the same birthday or have the same timestamp for a shift is data duplication? and therefore should be placed into another data table?

Comment: Since nobody stores birth dates in an extra table, there is no common date for 2 employees.

Comment: Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. This is too broad a question. Yet it is also a faq. Please see [ask] & other [help] links & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: [Understanding Normalization & Duplicates - I Guess I Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44539858/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

**Birth date** has full and non-transitive dependency to a person which means that it should be stored within the same table where you keep your employees and it would comply with third normal form (3NF).

**Work shifts** are not an attribute of an employee which means that they are a different entity and stay in relation with employee entity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a particular 'limit' when following the normalisation to data, since the main restriction that is given for every relational database table is to have an unique **parimary key**. Hence, if all other columns contain the same data, but the primary key is still different, it is a different row of a table.

The actual restrictions can come in two form. One is either the programming or systhematic approach, where the restriction on what kind of data is inputed is given from a program which interacts with the database or already defined script handed down physically for the admin of the database.

Other, more database-orriented approach would be to create primary keys composed of **multiple columns**. That way a row is unique only if for both columns the data is unique. It should be noted that a primary key is not necessary the same as an **unique key**, which should be different for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what normalization does.

- Two attributes having the same value (i.e. two employees having the same birthday) is not redundancy.
- Rather having the same attribute in the two tables (i.e. two tables having birthday column, therefore repeating every employee's birthday information) is.

---

Normalization is a quality decision and denormalization is a performance decision. For my school projects, my teachers recommended me to normalize at least till 3NF. So that may be a good guideline.